# CSS parent div border and height collapsing

Tags: css

Have a parent div and 3 child div's.  Know the height of child2 only.  Want the child1 and child3 to have the same height as height getting reduced. Also border of the parent is collapsing.  Want the border of parent to be visible around the child.
Pasted the code http://jsfiddle.net/586Cr/

Provided the code below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #parentt{
        background-color:#000000;
        border:4px solid #0000FF;
      }
      #child1{
        background-color:#000000;
        border:4px solid #FF0000;
        float:left;
        width:25%;
      }
      #child2{
        background-color:#000000;
        border:4px solid #FF0000;
        float:left;
        width:30%;
        height:100px;
      }
      #child3{
        background-color:#000000;
        border:4px solid #FF0000;
        width:25%;
        float:left;
      }
      .trans60 {
         zoom: 1;
         filter: alpha(opacity=60);
         opacity: 0.6;
      }
      .trans100 {
         zoom: 1;
         filter: alpha(opacity=100);
         opacity: 1.0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parentt">
      <div id="child1" class="trans60"> child1</div>
      <div id="child2" class="trans100">child2</div>
      <div id="child3" class="trans60">child3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think op got answer than this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `overflow:hidden` to your parent here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/586Cr/2/) because child's are floating.

Briefly 
 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Setting `overflow: hidden` on an element causes a new float context to be created, so elements that are floated inside an element that has `overflow: hidden` applied are cleared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Know the height of middle div only.  In the fiddle link u had set all the div's to the 100px.

Comment: oh you need  parent's border wrap around its child's even it's height's vary.? without showing any whites spaces..!

Comment: @Arav css3 flex-box may help you am sure it helps bcs it did't used yet..[check](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's start off!

Anytime you float, it tends to break the parent.  I know, children leave the parents broke.. it's just a habit we have in nature.

To fix this, I always make a class called 'clear' and just attach a div when I want to do clearing!  I find this to be more useful than doing an overflow: hidden, as the clear class can be reused nearly any and everywhere.

```
//css
.clear { clear: both; }

// calling it up after the 3 children
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Ok, so that fixes that problem.

Now to do the div height, that's not overly complicated with some jQuery.

Now I could go on trying to explain this, but it would take a minute.  Follow this tutorial:

Demo:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/plugin.html

Article:

http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/#.UoX-neKrTIU

However, instead of on click, do it at document ready.